# How to determine Gpio write mode

Tags: gpio, wiringpi

Hello I'm creating a cgi script to turn on one led (Red)  while blue is off and vice versa  it's more like a quiz buzzer 
Here's a code

```
#!/bin/bash
```

ch=gpio read 16
    if test $ch -eq 1
    then

```
gpio -g write 12 0
else
gpio -g write 12 1
fi
```

My Red led is in Pin 32 and blue in 36
And I want to determine whether one of the Pin  is in Write state 
I'm using Wiringpi
 is there any built in function that returns Boolean value of Pin write state? 
If not pls help me to get the code work
Thank you

Comment: Actually you are using the wiringPi gpio utility.  Have you looked at the documentation (**man gpio**)?

Comment: Yes I have looked into and found gpio read pinno Does the work but I'm unable to store the command returned value to a variable

Comment: Have a look at http://abyz.me.uk/rpi/pigpio/examples.html#Shell_gpiotest in particular `m=$(pigs mg $1) # save mode` and similar to show a way.

Comment: Usually you can use backticks to store results of a command in a variable: $ AA=\`date`
$ echo $AA
Wed Jan 17 09:18:27 EST 2018